# Partial fraction expansion - handling multiple roots

Tags: fractions, partial-fractions

I am trying to solve the partial fraction expansion of the following:

$X(z) = \dfrac{3-15z}{9z^2-6z+1}$.

So I calculated the roots of $9z^2 - 6z + 1$.

This gives $n_1 = n_2 = \frac{1}{3}$ 
and $9z^2-6z+1 = 9(z-\frac{1}{3})(z-\frac{1}{3})$.

Now I don't know how to deal with it.

If there were no factor $9$, I would take the approach $X(z) = \frac{A}{z-\frac{1}{3}} + \frac{B}{(z-\frac{1}{3})^2}$.

And if there were two different roots, $z_1$ and $z_2$, I'd take the approach $X(z) = \frac{A}{z-z_1} + \frac{B}{z-z_2}$.

But since neither of these two cases is what we have here, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Forget about the 9, then divide everything by it at the end?

Comment: or just use $\dfrac A {3z-1} + \dfrac B {(3z-1)^2}$

Comment: Factor out the $9$! We write $\frac{3-15z}{9(z-1/3)(z-1/3)} = \frac{3-15z}{9}\cdot \frac{1}{(z-1/3)(z-1/3)}$. And you know how to write that last factor (it's exactly as you have written). Thus you would end up with $\frac{3-15z}{9} \left(\frac{A}{z-1/3} + \frac{B}{(z-1/3)^2}\right) = \frac{3-15z}{9z^2-6z+1}$

Comment: Thanks to all of you! All your suggestions are helpful! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could absolutely do it your way:  \begin{align}
X(z)=\frac{3-15z}{9z^2-6z+1}&=\frac{3-15z}{9(z-\frac13)^2}\\
&=\frac19\bigg(\frac{3-15z}{(z-\frac13)^2}\bigg)\\
&=\frac19\bigg(\frac{A}{z-\frac13}+\frac{B}{(z-\frac13)^2}\bigg)
\end{align}

Not impossible, but not very nice.

Alternatively:
\begin{align}
X(z)=\frac{3-15z}{9z^2-6z+1}&=\frac{3-15z}{(3z-1)^2}\\
&=\frac{A}{3z-1}+\frac{B}{(3z-1)^2}\\
&=\frac{A(3z-1)+B}{(3z-1)^2}\\
&=\frac{3Az-A+B}{(3z-1)^2}\Rightarrow \left\{\begin{array} 
& 3A &=-15\\
-A+B&=3\end{array} \right. \Rightarrow (A,B)=(-5,-2)\\
&=-\frac{5}{3z-1}-\frac{2}{(3z-1)^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for listing both options! So now I also know how to deal with the factor if it hasn't a square root in the natural numbers. This was very helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use  $$\dfrac A {3z-1} + \dfrac B {(3z-1)^2}=\dfrac{3-15z}{(3z-1)^2}$$

whence   $$A(3z-1)+B=3-15z$$

so $B-A=3$ and $3A=-15$.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hi J. W. Tanner, thanks for your help! I didn't realize I could factor the 9. Now it's obvious. :)